# Exibir o resultado AJAX em uma popup

Tags: ajax

Estou tentando executar uma função que enviará dados de um formulário para um servidor e trará uma resposta para o usuário em uma popup com estilos CSS.

Não estou conseguindo exibir essa popup com o resultado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    function simulacao(nome, email, qtdMeses, vlrAluguel){

        $.ajax({
            url: url + "/api/simulacao",
            type: "POST",
            data: {nome, email, qtdMeses, vlrAluguel},
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.Status == "ok"){

                    $('#vlrSimulacao').text("Você pode receber até R$ " + data.Result);
                }
            }           
        });
    }

    $(function(){

        $("#nf-field-2").click(function(){              
            if($("[name='nome']").val() != ""
            && $("[name='email']").val() != ""
            && $("[name='nf-field-5']").val() != ""
            && $("[name='nf-field-4']").val() != ""){
                simulacao($("[name='nome']").val(), $("[name='email']").val(), $("[name='nf-field-5']").val(), $("[name='nf-field-4']").val());
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Você já viu se tem algum erro no console? O popup seria o `$('#vlrSimulacao')`?

Comment: mas onde vc abre a popup? não está nesse código

Comment: Opa, esqueci de colocar a div: 

<div id="vlrSimulacao"> </div>